# How to make the background image fill the offscreen when I apply a background-position transform?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How to make the background image fill the offscreen when I apply a background-position transform animation trough jquery?
As you can see,when the animation ends,the div is filled with white.

```
  .firstpage{
       background-image: url('bcb.png');
       min-height: 100vh;
       min-width: 100vh;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
     }

  $(".firstpage").animate({
     'background-position-y': '200px',
    });
```

The bcb.png image has a width of 2720px and a height of 1880px,so it's larger than my 100vh(1920x1080 resolution)

I've uploaded a quick video on YT just in case my question wasn't clear.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BSX2r8f5s4&feature=youtu.be